# Plotting zero phase signal

Tags: matlab, plot, signals

I need to plot zero phase signal without using filter , but I can't understand what I have to correct in my code to plot it right.

I expect to get this:
[image]

```
f1=20;
f2=100;
df=f2-f1; 
dt=0.002; 
T=4; 
handles.t=0:dt:T-dt; 
handles.s=sin(2.*pi.*handles.t.*(f1+(df/((T-dt)*2).*handles.t)));
handles.phase=angle(fft(handles.s));
handles.uphase =unwrap(handles.phase);
for k=1:1:length(handles.t)
 handles.zero(k)=abs(handles.s(k)).*cos(handles.uphase (k))+abs(handles.s(k)).*j.*sin(handles.uphase (k));
end 
handles.zero=real(ifft(handles.zero));
figure
plot(handles.t,handles.zero)
```

Comment: This is third time ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773886/plot-zero-phase-signal) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779905/making-complex-array)) you're posting this. Please stop deleting and reasking the same question.

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions. Edit your original question to include all the details.

Comment: Plotting the zero phase signal? Do you mean you need to set the phase of your signal to zero? That would be equivalent to taking the absolute value of the Fourier transform, then inverse transforming like you do here. I’m not sure this is what you actually want, though.

Comment: @CrisLuengo "Do you mean you need to set the phase of your signal to zero?" Exactly, can you help me to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a digital signal as a vector, say `signal`, then you can set its phase to zero simply by taking the magnitude of the Fourier transform:

```
new_signal = ifft(abs(fft(signal)));
```

`new_signal` here should be real-valued if `signal` is real-valued as well.